# Three.js PLY file not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, three.js, ply-file-format

I am trying to load PLY models from backend, however they aren't displaying correctly (those three mountains should be 3 models of scanned trees).
[image]
I tried to change mesh but it doesn't change the lines showing instead of points.
Code:

```js
public prepare3d():void{
var height= 400;
var width = this.rendererContainer.nativeElement.clientWidth;
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xEEEEEE );
const fov = 45;
const aspect = width / height;
const near = 1;
const far = 1000;
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, width / height, 0.1, 1000 );
camera.position.set( 3, 0.15, 3 );
var cameraTarget = new THREE.Vector3( 0, - 0.1, 0 );
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();

loader.load( '/assets/v1.ply', function ( geometry ) {
      geometry.computeVertexNormals();
      var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { color: 0x0055ff, flatShading: true } );
      var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

      mesh.position.y = 0;
      mesh.position.z = 0.3;
      mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
      mesh.scale.multiplyScalar( 0.001 );

      mesh.castShadow = true;
      mesh.receiveShadow = true;

      scene.add( mesh );

    });
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could show a working demo? It's very hard to debug your code when you show such a small snippet of it. The problem could be your camera, materials, assets, or any other number of things. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you need points, then use `THREE.Points()` and `THREE.PointsMaterial()` instead of `THREE.Mesh()` and `THREE.MeshStandardMaterial()`.

Comment: I have extended the portion of the code. Hope it shows more. 
I have tried using points and mesh, unfortunately it doesn't change anything.